# Make SQL*Plus not ask for defining input parameter if it is not present

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have an SQL*Plus script that takes an input parameter. Assume it's a `script.sql` having its contents like this:

```
define my_val=&1
prompt &my_val
```

When I run it like this `sqlplus /nolog @script.sql foo` it works fine and shows `foo`. But when I run it without a parameter `sqlplus /nolog @script.sql` I am prompted to set a value for `1`. Instead I want to leave it null and proceed with some "default" logic for my script.

How can I achieve such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped into [Vladimir Begun's blog post](https://vbegun.blogspot.com/2008/04/on-sqlplus-defines.html) where he describes quite a tricky way to achieve this. In my case `script.sql` would be like this

```
column def_val new_value 1 noprint
select null as def_val from dual where 1=0;

define my_val="&1"
prompt my_val="&my_val"
```

Calling it will result in:

```
SQL> @script.sql
my_val=""
SQL> @script.sql foo
my_val="foo"
SQL>
```

Note that it requires a connection to a database since you have to make a query. Also add quotes to `&1` as it is null when not provided so SQL*Plus complains about defining a variable with null value.

Comment: This does not answer the question: you invoke the script with the input `foo` and it returns `"foo"` with the double-quotes, unlike the desired behavior which is to return without the double-quotes. Between this and posting and answering your own question - which is not even your own answer, it's just telling us what you found on someone else's blog - that's a -1 from me on both the question and the answer, and hopefully many more from others, until you delete your post altogether.